# A method to convert ppm to ascii art doesn't work properly

Tags: c, output, ascii-art

I  wrote a program for converting a file from PPM format to ASCII art. Every pixel of the input image is converted to greyscale by calculating the average of red green and blue values ((red + green +blue)/3).

The upgrade of the basic version is that I calculate the average of RGB in a window of size n*n, and convert it to a character which would decrease the size of the image. So if the given number n is 3, the window is of size 3*3, which means that you sum all nine red, green and blue values and divide it by 3 times n*n (3*3 in this case). When the program counts the greyscale for the first window, it moves to the other one and so on until the end. When there is the end of width, it jumps down by the n number of pixels and reads the next line, etc.

When the greyscale is calculated it is then converted to a character and this character is being written to the output file to form an ASCII art image.

There is the code that should do this work:

```
    int x, y;
    for (x = 0; x < width; x++){ 
        for(y=0; y < height; y++){
            array[x][y][0] = fgetc(input); //red
            array[x][y][1] = fgetc(input); //green
            array[x][y][2] = fgetc(input); //blue

            int greyscale;
            // greyscale = (red + green +blue)/3;

            int blockx, blocky;
            for(blockx = 0; blockx < n; blockx+=n){
                for(blocky=0; blocky < n; blocky+=n){
                    greyscale = ((array[x][y][0] + array[x][y][1] +array[x][y][2])/(3*(n*n)));
                    char c = method_of_conversion(greyscale);
                    fprintf(output,"%c",c); // write ASCII art to the output file 
                }

            }   
        }fprintf(output,"\n");
    }
```

The output file for one ppm should look like this:

```
                    ..'::....'oo&&:..                                           
               ..:'#8@@oo#@@@@@@@@@8      .8&o              .&o.                
            ooo:'.'o88'    8@@@@@@@&                8'    '@@@@@@' .  .&..      
   '@@@8&'o8&:8@@'&#:@o@#   &@@@@@&         &@@o    .o'@8@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#o:&o
:& 8@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@8&.&@o  #@@'   #8     :@@8@@o@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
   &@@#o8@@@@@@@@@@   '@o.   :'          @@@ #@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@8:8&' 
    ..    &@@@@@@@@#&..@@@o           'o  :o.@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@&   .@    
           &@@@@@@@@@@#@@@@&          '8o@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@8        
            8@@@@@@@@@@@@8 &           &@@@@@@@@@@#:@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@.        
            #@@@@@@@@@@@:             8##:&'@@'..@&&@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@& &        
            '@@@@@@@@@@.              @@   '. @@@@@ @@@@@@@@@@@@@@: &  :        
             :@@@@@@@@&               8@@@&    .@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  &.         
              :@@@@:.8               :@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@             
               '@@.                 :@@@@@@@@@@#8@@&8''@@@@@@@@@@@:             
                '@&.o '.'           @@@@@@@@@@@@:@@@@  .@@@''@@8o               
                  &@&.              @@@@@@@@@@@@@o@&    &@   o@@  .             
                     : :o.          o@@@@@@@@@@@@@'.    .@    '@.  '            
                      :@@@@.         &@@#@@@@@@@@@@      .    :  . o            
                      o@@@@@@             @@@@@@@@.          .# '@              
                      @@@@@@@@o           @@@@@@@             8oo@o .8&'        
                      @@@@@@@@@@.         .@@@@@#              :&.    '@8       
                      .@@@@@@@@8           @@@@@@                    : '        
                       o@@@@@@@'          .@@@@@@ 8                :#@o8'       
                        &@@@@@@            @@@@@ .@              .&@@@@@@       
                        8@@@@&             @@@@8 .o              @@@@@@@@@      
                        @@@@@              .@@@                  o@@@@@@@@      
                        @@@@                @8                   '@o  #@@8      
                       :@@#                                            o&     .o
                       :@#                                              :    .: 
                       8@.                                                   '  
                       o#                                                       
                        '                                                       

                         .'                        ..       ...... . ..         
                        8@               ..:'.o#&@@@@@@:o@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#o.   
         ':8888&&@@@@8@@@@'         8@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@8.  
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

But my program outputs it like this:

```
                    ..'::....'oo&&:..   

               ..:'#8@@oo#@@@@@@@@@8    
  .8&o              .&o.                
            ooo:'.'o88'    8@@@@@@@&    
            8'    '@@@@@@' .  .&..      
   '@@@8&'o8&:8@@'&#:@o@#   &@@@@@&     
    &@@o    .o'@8@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#o:&o
:& 8@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@8&.&@o  #@@'   #8   
  :@@8@@o@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
   &@@#o8@@@@@@@@@@   '@o.   :'         
 @@@ #@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@8:8&' 
    ..    &@@@@@@@@#&..@@@o           'o
  :o.@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@&   .@    
           &@@@@@@@@@@#@@@@&          '8
o@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@8        
            8@@@@@@@@@@@@8 &           &
@@@@@@@@@@#:@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@.        
            #@@@@@@@@@@@:             8#
#:&'@@'..@&&@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@& &        
            '@@@@@@@@@@.              @@
   '. @@@@@ @@@@@@@@@@@@@@: &  :        
             :@@@@@@@@&               8@
@@&    .@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  &.         
              :@@@@:.8               :@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@             
               '@@.                 :@@@
@@@@@@@#8@@&8''@@@@@@@@@@@:             
                '@&.o '.'           @@@@
@@@@@@@@:@@@@  .@@@''@@8o               
                  &@&.              @@@@
@@@@@@@@@o@&    &@   o@@  .             
                     : :o.          o@@@
@@@@@@@@@@'.    .@    '@.  '            
                      :@@@@.         &@@
#@@@@@@@@@@      .    :  . o            
                      o@@@@@@           
  @@@@@@@@.          .# '@              
                      @@@@@@@@o         
  @@@@@@@             8oo@o .8&'        
                      @@@@@@@@@@.       
  .@@@@@#              :&.    '@8       
                      .@@@@@@@@8        
   @@@@@@                    : '        
                       o@@@@@@@'        
  .@@@@@@ 8                :#@o8'       
                        &@@@@@@         
   @@@@@ .@              .&@@@@@@       
                        8@@@@&          
   @@@@8 .o              @@@@@@@@@      
                        @@@@@           
   .@@@                  o@@@@@@@@      
                        @@@@            
    @8                   '@o  #@@8      
                       :@@#             
                               o&     .o
                       :@#              
                                :    .: 
                       8@.              
                                     '  
                       o#               

                        '               



                         .'             
           ..       ...... . ..         
                        8@              
 ..:'.o#&@@@@@@:o@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#o.   
         ':8888&&@@@@8@@@@'         8@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@8.  
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a third question with the same topic you are posting in the last few hours.

Comment: I know. I just want to make it work.

Comment: Can you try to reduce all the code here to the minimum amount of code that still exhibits the problem?

Comment: Looks like you are reading the width of the ppm file incorrectly.  See how you have bands of nearly correct data.  Double check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have copied your output to a text editor. I found that after column 40 a carriage return/linefeed was inserted. Removing it revealed your original image. I cannot explain this linefeed. I find it funny though that your outer loop iterates over the width and your inner loop over the height. I would expect that the other way around, printing one horizontal line for each y-line.